# SVN: delete one commited version from SVN "show log" list

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In My office 4 members are working on a project. We are using **tortoisesvn**. One member mistakenly committed a wrong file. I don't want to update that file. If I update my "project" by folder then **that wrong committed** file will automatically update to my computer.

So I want to **delete that wrong committed file** so that it'll not update to my computer.

How will I delete that committed file?

Can anyone help me please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deleting it from history is hard.  It's supposed to be, svn is all about keeping history.

It sounds like you'll be find if you revert the change, the [undoing changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo) section of the doc is really good.

Comment: :( . Yes I know undo is the better option. but the file had closed.

Comment: closed?  I don't understand what you're trying to say there.

Comment: the file is closed from the editor. So not possible undo the code(rollback).

Comment: Reverting a change committed to the svn repository has nothing to do with the editor.  Read the link in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

For **deleting committed files** - You need to follow below steps:-

1. Right click on the committed file from Your local server.
2. click Showlog from Tortoisesvn option.
3. then delete the version of that file which You want to delete. or reverse back to another version.

that's all You need to follow.